# Buffer 1 to 1 relation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, buffer, intersect

I have 2 layers ( geometric type - point), let's name it layer A and layer B. I need to find which points from layer B don't have their equivalents points from layer A. So i`ve made 10 meter buffer around points A and found which interestcs with points from layer B. So now I have a group of points from layer B which are intersected with buffers so they have equivalents points in A, and I can also find points from layer B which don't have equivalent points in A. But there is a chance that 2 buffers from layer A can intersect with 1 (the same) point from layer B. How can I find which 2 buffers from layer A are intersected to the same point. Or maybe on the other way - which point from layer B is intersected to 2 or more buffers?

[image]

The problem is in the 3 example, where 2 buffers are intersected to one point. How i can find that buffers?

I am using QGIS.

Comment: What software are you using? If you're using ArcGIS you can use the [Intersect (analysis) tool](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//00080000000p000000).

Comment: Im using qgis. Sorry I forgot to notice that

Comment: If, using your third example, that  two layer A buffers intersect the same layer B point, would the layer B buffer intersect both layer A points? if so you could just use the layer B buffer and the tool 'Count Points in polygon'.  Then its a simple task of querying back to those original Layer A points.

Comment: i thought about it too but there is a chance that buffer B won`t intersect with both points from A because its much closer to one of points. And if i set bigger buffer it might cover 3th point. We can say it works cause I know that there is more than 1 point but to be honest it`s not a perferct solution when I have 5k points or more.

@edit and it also shows the relation 2-2 which is supposed to be correct.

Comment: You can see my approach with PyQGIS.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using PyQGIS. In the next code, 'combination' method from **itertools** module it does possible to search (avoiding repetition) features which are producing intersection in the buffer layer. Afterward, at the same loop, it can be searched if a point of second point layer is within the intersection area. Results, as features indices of buffer layer, are printed at the Python Console of QGIS.

```
import itertools

registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

layer_A = registry.mapLayersByName('layer_A')
layer_B = registry.mapLayersByName('layer_B')

feats_layerA = [ feat for feat in layer_A[0].getFeatures() ]

feats_layerB = [ feat for feat in layer_B[0].getFeatures() ]

list = range(len(feats_layerA))

for i,j in itertools.combinations(list, 2):
    if feats_layerA[i].geometry().intersects(feats_layerA[j].geometry()):
        geom = feats_layerA[i].geometry().intersection(feats_layerA[j].geometry())

        for feat_b in feats_layerB:
            if feat_b.geometry().within(geom):
                print "yes", i, j
```

For testing my approach, I used shapefiles of next image where it is also observed, printed at the Python Console of QGIS, indices of features buffer layer whose intersection has a point of second layer.

[image]